# Paint tool for OS X with specific features

Tags: gratis, osx, graphic-design, animation, pixel-graphics

I am using gimp as my paint program for game graphics, but I want something that have auto straight tool, make the line straight, and isometric grid. I will like program for Sketching and low-poly art. It can also have stock photos and icons available. It should drag and move for animations. It should be free. It should have layers. Transparency of layer. Text function with lots of fonts.

Do you know some?

I am running Mac OS X.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details. What OS should it run on? What other features are needed? Btw, as for "straight lines", ever tried holding the Shift key when drawing a line in Gimp? And checked the options for showing a grid?

Comment: In Gimp is not any “normal” way to make isometric grid. Thanks for the straight function

Comment: Would using [a GIMP plugin](https://www.sl-inspiration.com/2018/01/how-to-create-isometric-images-in-gimp.html) solve that part? There's also a [video tutorial](https://invidious.snopyta.org/watch?v=5iRb0oAS21g) for that plugin. For more, your favorite search engine will help when asked for `gimp "isometric grid"` ;) // Thanks for the update!

Comment: Thanks I don’t know that plugin exist!

Comment: If that fits your needs, be welcome to [answer your own question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) (and accept that answer). Before you ask why I don't make that an answer: I didn't test it; I just used a search engine as described in my previous comment and had it pop up in the results. So my posting that wouldn't make a quality answer – while your answer could show *how* it fits ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved:
I found that GIMP have plugins and tools that I think they don’t exist. I will stay with GIMP! Thanks for all recommendations and tips about gimp!

Tips I learned:

- Hold shift to make straight line
- There are hundrents off plugins for everything you like such as isometric grid
- GIMP is still one of the best paint tool for game graphics for free
- you can rotate squares to make them feel like isometric.

Isometric grid plugin:

https://www.sl-inspiration.com/2018/01/how-to-create-isometric-images-in-gimp.html

Resynthesizer plugin:

https://github.com/aferrero2707/gimp-plugins-collection/releases

Comment: And I just +1 your answer. You should probably wait a day or two in case another answer gets posted and then accept the best one by clicking the check mark icon. It is perfectly acceptable to accept your own answer.

Comment: Thanks for your interest and spending time with newbies such as me!

Comment: Thanks for self-answering and summing up, @Maratonec – +1 also from me! And another pointer: While in the past there was the [Gimp Registry](https://www.gimp.org/registry/) where you could find plugins, brushes etc, the GIMP team plans to integrate that directly with GIMP – probably in a way like Firefox integrates an interface to its addons. Something to look forward to! Enjoy GIMP :)